# Can a city go from a population of 5000 people to 50000 in a 600-year period?

Tags: medieval, population

I have a few cities in my story that have anywhere from 30000 people to 70000 people. Is it possible that these cities have blossomed to such a number in a span of 600 to 700 years? I am going to give some specs of the movement of people in these periods:

- 700 years ago: a people invade the territory where the cities are currently, sort of like the migration period in history.
- 600 years ago: the area is finally occupied by the people who invaded (loss of life in this period of 100 years was almost constant through wars and skirmishes).
- 580 years ago: a rebellion starts in the indigenous population of the territory, that lasts for a few years.
- 500 years ago: the people that invaded form clans in the sub-territories where the cities are currently located, and they start fighting amongst each other for the whole of the territory.
- 400 years ago: all the people of the territory are united under one rule. Since then, no major wars or plagues have happened in the territory, although there have been a few minor skirmishes.

The cities before invasions 700 years ago were small centers of trade that held a max of 4000-5000 people. The technology advanced a bit quicker (compared to Earth) in the ''medieval'' period of the world because of reasons I'm not willing to share. I'll say that the current technology and knowledge in the book is somewhere on the level of Earth’s Renaissance Period.

Thanks for any opinions and answers in advance.

Comment: -1 for not doing your own research.  Google "London population history", first hit is http://www.demographia.com/dm-lon31.htm.  Or look up the population of Paris over time on wikipedia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Paris#/media/File:Paris_historical_population_1.png

Comment: @pojo-guy has a point: There are numerous historical examples within the range you are asking. Some cities gained population (a few quite rapidly at times), others lost population. Remember that 700 years can be a very long time - that's much longer than it took the fierce [Maygyar invaders of central Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_invasions_of_Europe) to settle down, become farmers, change religions, form a western-style Kingdom, and finally to become Hapsburg subjects. It's not much shorter than Europe's *entire* medeival period.

Comment: You don't even have to look at historical cities New York City didn't exist 600 years ago and now look at it.

Comment: Population of Rome went from 30 thousand around 1300 to almost 3 million near end of 20th century: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=population+of+rome+over+time

Comment: *All* the major cities in the U.S. of A. went from zero population in 1700 to millions of inhabitatnts in 2000.

Comment: @Alex P a few major cities in the USA covering hundreds square miles had a few Indian villages of a few tens or hundreds of people each before the European settlers arrived, so what you said is only about 99 % accurate.  But certainly most cities of 50,000 or more in the USA had fewer than 5,000 inhabitants 600 years ago in 1418.

Comment: yes, they can become ten times the size within ten years, if you habve modern technology they could go from 500 to a million in a single year. You don't have to justify that kind of stuff, not really.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly possible: Rome started as a small village in 753 BCE (according to the legend) and then in 100 BCE had a population of 400000 people, reaching 1000000 in 100 CE. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_cities_throughout_history))

As long as you can supply enough food to the people living there, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

To Pou don't need 60o years,  humans are more then capable of doubling their population every 20 years.

with 5000 (innit pop)
10,000 (20 years)
20,000 (40 years)
40,000 (60 years)
80,000 (80 years)

The only limiting factors are food, disease, and war, when disease and war usually coming about as a result of a lack of food.

Comment: .. and you did not even mentioned immigration, which can be much faster.